# symfony 3.4 Redirect 301 with the locale in URL

Tags: .htaccess, symfony, redirect, vhosts

I would like to put in place a Redirect 301, only if the url does not contains '/en/' :

> /app_dev.php => /app_dev.php/en

So, I did this in my vhost :

```
# Add locale [en] if not in URL
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[a-z]{2}/
RewriteRule ^(.*) /en/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But I am redirect here :

> /en/app_dev.php

An idea?

Comment: `$1/en/ ` instead of `/en/$1` ?

Comment: Why language after file? Don't you think `/en/app_dev.php/` is fine?

Comment: @Federkun Hi, no because I need /app_dev.php/slug => /app_dev.php/en/slug , and not => /app_dev.php/slug/en

Comment: @vivek_23 Hi, because /en/app_dev.php/ does not work :/ because the DocumentRoot is /var/www/website/web/

Comment: @Greg That doesn't make much sense to me. You will need to change your directory structure. It's weird to point to a folder after you have pointed to a file in the http request. Or else, make `en` reside in your query string.

Comment: @Greg It might make life easier to do this within your Symfony routing.  That will also ensure that it works in your other environments.  You can use the RedirectController (FrameworkBundle:Redirect:redirect) directly in your route(s).